# Prevent packages like typescript from overriding autocomplete in sublimetext?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package

I installed typescript package in sublime text, and now the typescript keywords replaced my variable names in the autocomplete.

This happens with big sublime packages. How to prevent it (how to prioritize local variable names over specific package types)?

**Edit:**
I just realized that with typescript, the autocomplete is only overridden in the class attribute definition:

```
export class BClass extends AClass {
    // autocomplete is overridden here
    attribute: number
    constructor() {
        // autocomplete is normal here
        this.attribute = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TypeScript`'s case, the completions are coming from `sublime-snippet` files.

You can override the `class` snippet with the following process:

- Install [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)
- Run the `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` command from the `command palette`
- Navigate to `TypeScript/snippets/class-{-}.sublime-snippet`
- Comment out the entire contents of `class-{-}.sublime-snippet` and save the file